# How can I edit my cookies in Safari Web Inspector?

Tags: safari, cookies

I could not edit value of cookies.

How can I edit my cookies in Safari  Web Inspector?

Comment: The first senate implies you tried - what did you try ?and what sort of edit are you trying to do?

Answer (score 19):

Entries in this table are read-only; if you want to edit a cookie’s value, you need to do so with the document.cookie object in JavaScript (you can use the Quick Console at the bottom of the content browser to modify the cookie and see the results update in real time). Pressing the Delete key while a cookie is selected deletes the cookie.

please reference [Safari Web Inspector Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html)

Comment: What if you want to test for local mobile development? Then this doesn't work.

Comment: How to edit httpOnly cookies?

Comment: in dev console do `document.cookie = "key=value";` then refresh the cookies.

Comment: To adjust the expiry date of an existing cookie I used this in dev console to give it a far future date: ``document.cookie = "VerifiedClick=clicked; path=/; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT"``

Comment: @oluies I rolled back your edit as it replaced a deep link with a link just pointing at the TOC. Is the inspector guide part of the new manual, can it be linked to directly?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't edit cookies in the default browser safari in Mac.
Try using third-party plugins like [safaricookiecutter](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10625/safaricookiecutter)
or use firefox web browser and use firebug.

Comment: SafariCookieCutter has been discontinued